# Why doesn't Qsys let me connect two conduits together by complaining that they do not have associated resets?

Tags: quartus

```
Error: MYSYSTEM.: Interfaces My_Design_0.to_debug_regs_conduit_out and DEBUG_REGISTERS_0.my_conduit_in must have matching associated resets, but My_Design_0.to_debug_regs_conduit_out has no associated reset.
```

I have associated resets assigned in both places. It must be noted that while the debug_regs has only one clock domain and thus a single reset, there are two clock domains in the my design and thus two resets.

EDIT:

In the Qsys system it can be seen that for one component the reset for clk_33 is connected to two resets, one for clk_33 and another for clk_132. For the other component, the reset is connected to clk_33 only. This is what generates the error. Now, if I connect the 2nd component's reset to two reset sources as well i.e one for clk_33 and another for clk_132, then the error message goes away.

What this means is that I just need to make sure that the reset signal on the two components is connected to the same reset sources. I am not sure why the person who created this Qsys system connected reset_33 (source) output to reset_33 and reset_132 inputs on the component and then also connected the reset_132 (source) output to reset_33 and reset_132 inputs on the component. It does look strange to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

As you have seen, Qsys is complaining because one conduit has an associated reset and the other doesn't, which means as far as it is concerned, one of them could randomly reset without the other one knowing about it can then potentially cause an issue.

What settings have you used in your TCL file for each component?
You should see something like the following:

```
set_interface_property to_debug_regs_conduit_out associatedClock clock
set_interface_property to_debug_regs_conduit_out associatedReset reset
```

That is where the reset signal is "associated" with the conduit (where `reset` is the name of your reset connection). If the two don't match then it will get upset.

Using a value of `""` indicates no associated reset.